# check the existence of a site user using curl and nginx

Tags: nginx, curl, cookies

On my site, registered users, after logging in, have the possibility to download files with the curl command, i.e.

```
curl -O https://example.com /assets/file/test.txt
```

I would like to somehow avoid that the user not logged in or deleted still has the possibility to download the file by running the command again or by going directly to the address from the browser.

I use Nginx as web server.

Is it possible to block access to the user that no longer exists or is no longer logged in?

I had thought about the possibility of doing something like this:

```
curl -u {{user.id}}:{{unique_value}} https://example.com/assets/file/test.txt
```

or

```
curl -O https://example.com/assets/file/test.txt?param={{unique_value}}
```

But I don't know how to verify the existence of the user, and if it is possible to do so, with nginx or some other tool.

I tried using cookie control with Nginx, but as far as I know it is easy to circumvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah you can use http basic auth to restrict file access to authorized people, per the documentation at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

```
touch /etc/nginx/users.htpasswd;
htpasswd /etc/nginx/users.htpasswd user1 'password';
```

followed by

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80
        location /assets{
            root /wherever/assets/..;
            auth_basic           "assets";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users.htpasswd; 
        }
}
```

now only `curl -u user1:password1`  can download files in /assets/

Comment: But users are from the site, saved in the database, not in that file. Should I put every user of my site in the file?

Comment: @exper_1 yeah make some database<->htpasswd sync script, so whenever a new account is created in the db, one is created in htpasswd as well, whenever a password is changed, it's changed in htpasswd as well

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the information, I think it's the best solution!